# On the property of inner product

Tags: real-analysis, inner-products

If $f$ and $g$ are complex-valued continuous Z-periodic functions, then by definition, $\|f + g\|_2^2 - \|f - g\|_2^2 = \int_0^{1}((f + g)(\overline{f + g}) - (f - g)(\overline{f - g})) = \int_0^{1}2(f\overline{g} + \overline{f}g) = 4\Re\int_0^{1}f\overline{g} = 4\Re\langle f,g\rangle = 2\langle f + g,f + g\rangle.$

On the other hand, it also seems that $\|f + g\|_2^2 - \|f - g\|_2^2 = \langle f + g,f + g\rangle - \langle f - g,f - g\rangle = \langle f + g,f + g\rangle + \langle f - g,-(f - g)\rangle = 2\langle f,g \rangle.$

What is this disparity and where exactly do I misunderstand?

Comment: In both of these the last equalitities are wrong.

Comment: The last step of the first equality uses the fact that $4\Re\langle f,g\rangle =4 \cdot\frac{1}{2}(\langle f,g\rangle + \overline{\langle f,g\rangle}) = 4 \cdot\frac{1}{2}(\langle f,g\rangle + \langle g,f\rangle) = 2\langle f+g,f+g\rangle$. The last step of the second equality uses linearity.

Comment: As @KaviRamaMurthy said, that's wrong. In your comment, you use $\langle f,g\rangle+\langle g,f\rangle=\langle f+g,f+g\rangle$, which is wrong since it omits terms $\langle f,f\rangle+\langle g,g\rangle$.

Comment: And your second equation lost two terms,  each equal to $\langle g,f\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you, I see it now. @Andreas Blass.